# classList fallback (IE & older browsers)

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel, cross-browser

I'm trying to make some **JS** code more browser compatible. So I've written an alternative to **JS**'s `classList` providing its `.add()`, `.remove()` and `.toggle()` functionality because it is not or just partially supported in IE.

(I know there are exiting polyfills, but I like to have a good overview regarding my code.)

My test were successful but before I use it extensively I wanted to check with someone if they see any issues.

```
    function classes(type, element, targetClass){
            var classArray = element.className.split(/\s/);
            var index = classIndex(classArray, targetClass);
            // if target class is in class list
            if(index !== null){
                // multiple classes
                if(classArray.length > 1){
                    if(type == "remove" || type == "toggle") {
                        classArray.splice(index, 1);
                        element.className = classArray.join(" ");
                    }
                }
                // single class
                else {
                    if(type == "remove" || type == "toggle") {
                        element.className = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            // if target class is not in class list
            else {
                if(type == "add" || type == "toggle") {
                    element.className += " " + targetClass;
                }
            }
            // check if target class is in class list (returns index or null)
            function classIndex(array, targetClass){
                for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                    if(array[i]==targetClass){
                        return i;
                    }
                    if(i==(array.length-1)){
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Usage:

```
classes("toggle", myElement, "classToToggle")
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a big fan of neither the function name `classes` nor the parameter name `type`. Something like `modifyClassOfElement` and `action` would be better fitting.

You should define constants for the `type`/`action` values.

It's convention in JavaScript to have a space between keywords and a following open bracket: `if  (`

In `classIndex` the second `if` is unnecessary. Just put `return null;` after the loop. Or, even better, you can replace the whole function with an `.indexOf()` call.

Move `if (type == "remove" || type == "toggle") {` up one level so you don't need it twice. Alternatively I'd just drop the special case for a single class, as it's an tiny optimization that is hardly worth it.

Remove one level of brackets on the final else:

```
else if (type == "add" || type == "toggle") {
  element.className += " " + targetClass;
}
```

I'd consider throwing an exception, if the `type`/`action` is unknown to aid debugging.

It would be nice for the function to use `classList` if it's available. Personnally I'd implement this as a function that returns an existing `classList` or an object that implements the same interface ([`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList))

Answer (score 1):

@RoToRa: thanks for your suggestions, I edited my code:

- called it `classAction` (wanted something short but hey - anyone could name it to gusto)
- made the suggested simplifications
- couldn't replace the `classIndex()` function with `indexOf()` though since `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is only supported by IE9+ (thus it would defeat the whole purpose of using this)
  [MDN on Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility)
- added `.contains()` functionality
- checks if `classList` is available in `Element.prototype`

> You should define constants for the type/action values.

why/how would I do that?

**New Code:**

```
function classAction(action, element, targetClass) {
  if (!('classList' in Element.prototype)) {
    var classArray = element.className.split(/\s/);
    var index = classIndex(classArray, targetClass);
    if (index !== null) {
      if (action == "remove" || action == "toggle") {
        if (classArray.length > 1) {
          classArray.splice(index, 1);
          element.className = classArray.join(" ");
        } 
        else {
          element.className = "";
        }
      } 
      else if (action == "contains") {
        return true;
      }
    } 
    else if (action == "add" || action == "toggle") {
      element.className += " " + targetClass;
    } 
    else if (action == "contains") {
      return false;
    }
    function classIndex(array, targetClass) {
      for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == targetClass) {
          return i;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  } 
  else {
    switch (action) {
      case "add":
        element.classList.add(targetClass);
        break;
      case "remove":
        element.classList.remove(targetClass);
        break;
      case "toggle":
        element.classList.toggle(targetClass);
        break;
      case "contains":
        if (element.classList.contains(targetClass)) {
          return true;
        } 
        else {
          return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```